# what is the difference between these two malloc declarations?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, character

what is the difference between these two malloc functions?

```
char *s; //declaration

--> s = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));

--> s=(char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
```

Do here too, we need to typecast the malloc function if it is already declared in char

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You never cast the return value of malloc, so the first version is correct. On an unrelated note, there's an alternative syntax you can use to specify the size: sizeof(char[1024]). Doesn't have anything to do with malloc, just a little syntactic sugar which i personally rather like

Comment: `malloc()` returns a `void*` which is implicitly converted into `int*` in C, so it doesn't make any difference and therefore the second line is redundant and does nothing more than making the code harder to read. Unrelated, but, this is different in case of C++ where you need to actually cast the result of `malloc()` because C++ doesn't allow implicit conversion of `void*` to `int*`.

Comment: @FelixG: I like that syntax too, but if the size is not a compile-time constant, it only works with compilers which implement variable length arrays (VLAs). VLAs are an optional feature in the current C standard thanks to lobbying from a vendor who apparently has no interest in implementing the feature.

Answer (score 0):

The second case is not preferred, the cast is not needed. Use the first syntax.